# Adding a character to every word in a cell in Excel w/ option to skip certain words

Tags: excel, vba

I'm completely lost and need some expert advice.

In [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) I have a column full of keywords, and I want to be able to use a macro that adds a "+" before every word, with the exception of a set of words that don't need it.

So basically in the VBA code there needs to be a place where I can say "skip the words 'the, for, with," etc.

*Edit: I've only found code that allows to append to the beginning of every cell. So that's close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I couldn't find anything closer to what I needed.*

```
Sub Add_Plus() 

Dim r As Range 

With Selection 

    For Each r In Selection 
        r.Value = "+" & r.Value 
    Next 

End With 

End Sub
```

***DOUBLE EDIT -***

You guys are awesome! We're super close, I just need the macro to add the + sign to every word in each cell, with the exception of the ones specified as exceptions. Thanks so much!

So the output we're looking for would be this:

Cell 1 before macro: **the happy dog jumps for joy**
Cell after macro: **the +happy +dog +jumps for +joy**

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you can use an if statement to skip the words. Please try something first than ask questions where you are having problems.

Comment: You can also do this as a formula, if it's okay for the results to be in a separate column.

Comment: show a sample of cell value which you have now and which you expect to have after...

Comment: Amazing how your piece of code had confused everyone!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how I understood your question- every word with the cell should have "+" except words which are excluded.

Try the following code. See some comments below

```
Sub Add_Plus()

Dim r As Range
Dim SkipWords As Variant
    'put all excluded word here, separate, within quotation marks
    SkipWords = Array("place", "all", "words", "to", "skip", "here")


Dim tmpWords As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim Final As String, boExclude As Boolean
    For Each r In Selection
        tmpWords = Split(r.Value, " ")
            For i = 0 To UBound(tmpWords)
                For j = 0 To UBound(SkipWords)
                    If UCase(SkipWords(j)) = UCase(tmpWords(i)) Then
                        'do nothing, skip
                        boExclude = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                If boExclude = False Then
                    Final = Final & "+" & tmpWords(i) & " "
                Else
                    'this will keep excluded words without "+"
                     'remove it if you want to remove the excluded words
                    Final = Final & tmpWords(i) & " "
                End If
                boExclude = False
            Next i
            r = Left(Final, Len(Final) - 1)
            Final = ""
    Next

End Sub
```

After you run the code the following cells:

```
do re mi
fa sol la
do place all
to words skip
here do re
place all
```

will be replace into:

```
+do +re +mi 
+fa +sol +la 
+do place all 
to words skip 
here +do +re 
place all
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Just use some logic to determine when to skip the words:

```
Sub Add_Plus()

Dim r As Range
Dim words As Variant
Dim word As Variant
Dim w As Long
Dim exclude As Variant
'Allow user-input to capture a list/array of words to exclude:
exclude = Split(Replace(Application.InputBox("Enter a comma-separated list of words to exclude"), " ", vbNullString), ",")
    For Each r In Selection.Cells
        'Create an array of "words" from the cell:
        words = Split((r.Value), " ")
        w = LBound(words)
        ' iterate over each "word"
        For Each word In words
            'Make sure the word is not in the excluded list
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(word, exclude, False)) Then
                '    DO NOTHING
            Else
                ' Add the "+" to these words:
                     words(w) = "+" & word
            End If
            w = w + 1
        Next
        r.Value = Join(words, " ")
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is so close! This still adds + signs to the beginning of the cell, but not every word. I really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Ahhh I thought you only needed the + at the beginning. Let me revise :)

Comment: I see KazJaw beat me to it, but I've updated my answer anyways.  Hope it helps.

Comment: This works as well! I'm still figuring out which one would be best. Quick question (and this might be a huge pain in the ass, so i apologize) but is there a way to prompt for which words to exclude? So they can be different each time the macro is run? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, try the revision now :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with a formula.

Assuming the "skip words" are in column A of Sheet2, then:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A1)=0,"+","")&A1
```

will do it.

Comment: This added three + signs to the beginning of the cell, instead of the beginning of each word in the cell. If there's a formula solution then that'd be even better!

Answer (score 0):

Select your cells and run this:

```
Sub dural()
    For Each r In Selection
    If r.Value <> "happy" And r.Value <> "sad" Then
        r.Value = "+" & r.Value
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Change the exclusions to meet your needs.